# Is this.init = function() called every time file is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, init

I can't find a definitive answer if an init function is called automatically when the file is loaded. Is this a built-in part of JS/Jquery, or am I missing where it's getting called from in some location of another file?

If it is being called automatically, is this reoccurring every time the file is loaded?

Example of the particular setup:

```
ExampleClass = function()
{
   this.init = function()
   {
          //...
   }
}
```

Comment: in your example there is no code ever being called, only defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no init is not called automatically when file is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Something else is calling it, that is not a behavior of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Init is called when DOM is ready, not called default or automatically when file is loaded.

Please see below link for more understanding.You will definitely like it.

[Click me](http://www.planetframework.com/documentation/1.10/Developing/Templates/Templates-in-depth/init-function-in-components-JavaScript-file/)